# AngularJs Web app skeleton template

Tags: angularjs

I am thinking of creating a web app using `angularjs` for learning purposes from scratch.

And I need to know what are the tools I can use to generate a basic structure of my app as starting point for development.

I've found `angular-seed` from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed). Now, what are other options we can use? Possibly `pros` and `cons`.

I know I can use angularjs like on ASP.NET website.

This question will generate an opinionated responses but this could help me determine what direction I should take before starting :)

Comment: Angular is a framework. What's your question?

Comment: @Phix ok, my mistake, removed that framework thing :)

Comment: yeoman has a generator for angular1. for angular2 the angular team have release their own generation stuff, i believe its called the angular cli.

Answer (score 1):

`AngularJS` is a client side `MVC` framework to create a fast website. Anyways it won't replace `ASP.NET` as it's a server side framework.

Using AngularJS, you can create a `SPA` which means **S**ingle **P**age **A**pplication.

When you choose to use `AngularJS` as client side framework, you have to still choose the server side framework such as `ASP.NET`, `NodeJS`, `PHP`, `JAVA` etc.

`Angular-seed` which you mentioned above is the good starter for beginners which is using `NodeJS` as server side `runtime` and you can start it by carefully following the instructions given in the `github` page.

If you intend to choose `ASP.NET` or `MVC` as your server side programming, you can follow the instructions given in the below links to start.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/angular

http://codehandbook.org/web-app-using-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc-4/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Answer (score 1):

An option which I use and could be useful to you too is [**Yeoman**](http://yeoman.io/).

> **What's Yeoman?**
>
> Yeoman helps you to kickstart new projects, prescribing best practices
>   and tools to help you stay productive.

Simply install using:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular
```

Get started [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) using:

```
yo angular [app-name]
```

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look in this also. Thanks

Comment: Happy hacking! :)